# How to forward internal Ethernet ip:port to localhost:port on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, portforwarding, lan

I have a relatively crude linux machine, with a setup that enables me to use my RPI through it since it's wifi doesn't work.

The RPI's ip is `10.42.0.206` and I can ssh to it just fine through the machine. But I want to also be able to access it on other devices, one thing I though was to forward `10.42.0.206:22` to something like `192.168.1.13:5022` (the ubuntu's ip) but I can't figure it out to make it work, could someone please help?

Do I make a proxy or something, idk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was right about the proxy part. For anyone that needs it, here's the answer:

1. Install simpleproxy: `sudo apt-get install simpleproxy`
2. Run it: `simpleproxy -L 5022 -R 10.42.0.206:22`

replace the port `5022` with your port or use `ip:port` and replace `10.42.0.206:22` with your internal `ip:port`